# Netdisco for Ubuntu server

Tags: 12.04, server, network-manager

Has anyone had luck installing netdisco through `apt-get`? I couldn't get it to work. I tried `netdisco-frontend`, `netdisco-backend`, `netdisco-common`, `netdisco-installer`.

I used the command:

```
sudo apt-get install netdisco-common netdisco-frontend netdisco-backend
```

Everything installed fine, but I can't get it running. It doesn't seem to have install to `/usr/local/netdisco/`.

I have looked all over the internet and there doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this.

I use server 12.04. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew sudo apt-get install netdisco-common netdisco-frontend netdisco-backend. Everything installed fine, but I can't get it running. I thought it would install to /usr/local/netdisco/

Answer (score 2):

On this website you can download a script that does the setup in about 15 minutes, fully working. Cheers.

http://netdisco.blogspot.se

Answer (score 0):

When you use your package manager to install software, it usually doesn't go to `/usr/local`. Debian, Ubuntu and many other distributions try to setup software according to the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS).

If you want to see where the files of netdisco are, you can open a shell and enter `dpkg -L netdisco-backend`. Now you see a listing of files and where they are stored.

Debian-based installations set the home to `/usr/lib/netdisco`. The configuration is at `/etc/netdisco/netdisco.conf`. Furthermore in `/usr/share/doc/netdisco*` there are several `README` files. They describe where you find files and what to do after installation.